# Tracing `getaddrinfo()` on OSX

Tags: macos, dtrace, getaddrinfo

There's a program that is spending a long time in `getaddrinfo()`. Is there any way on OSX to see what address  it is looking up? I've tried using [this DTrace script](https://github.com/brendangregg/DTrace-book-scripts/blob/master/Chap7/getaddrinfo.d) but unfortunately I get this error:

> dtrace: failed to compile script ./getaddrinfo.d: line 20: probe description pid16924::getaddrinfo:entry does not match any probes

Comment: Did you try replacing getaddrinfo with _*getaddrinfo*_ in the probe? The probe tries to match the name of the function exactly, unless there are wildcard characters, and it’s rarely possible to do that

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work - which I expected because there is nothing like `getaddrinfo` listed in `dtrace -l`.

Comment: You might do better interposing on the `getaddrinfo()` function call.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609728/changing-function-reference-in-mach-o-binary

Comment: Does adding `-Z` to the `dtrace` invocation help?